# Getting a FirebaseException ( [ Invalid authority field:[http: ] ) when trying to use FireBaseAuth on the Firebase Local Emulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have an Android flutter app that I have connected to flutter and have setup the Firebase config successfully, and I have set it up to connect to a local Firebase emulators.

Emulators Enabled:

- Firestore: working fine. I can query documents
- Authentication: Getting an exception: [ Invalid authority field:[http: ]

Full error log:

```
I/flutter ( 8905): [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid authority field:[http: ]
```

```
 firebase_core: ^1.4.0
 firebase_auth: ^3.0.0
 cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
 google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
```

FirebaseAuth emulator at: 10.0.2.2:9099

My project's config in Firebase is also set up (Sha1 keys are set, etc). I'm trying to login using Google Sing In.
What other config might I be missing that is causing the exception?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

For Emulator:
remove "http://" from firebaseAuth url, use only ip like "10.0.2.2" and port

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of `Firebase Auth` plugin, we used to write the port information in the url itself like

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9099';
// and then call useAuthEmulator like below
await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(url);
```

but in later versions of `Firebase Auth`, the `useAuthEmulator` function was changed to accept the domain and port separately. Now its like below.

```
var url = 'localhost'; // Note you don't have to mention the protocol http or https
var port = 9099;
// and then call useAuthEmulator like below
await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(url,port);
```

It seems like you were using an earlier version of `Firebase Auth` plugin, and then did a `pub upgrade`, thus, you changed to the second form shown above. But most probably, you might have forgotten to remove the protocol or port from the `url`.

Answer (score -2):

check your HTTP link and write it again

Comment: Please explain a little bit more. What link? The link to the auth emulator?

Comment: One line answers don't help much. This should have been a comment.